# setter method of the computed property does not get called

Tags: vue.js

in the below posted code, i am learning how to use the setter method of a computed property.
what i am trying to do, is when the user clicks the button and the counter increases consequently, the setter method should receive the following string

```
counter.value.toString() + " " + counter.value.toString()
```

and consequently, the `inputFirstName.value` and `inputLastName.value` should contain the value of `counter.value.toString()`

but at run time,when i increment the counter by clicking the button, both of `inputFirstName` and `inputLastName` remain unchanged.

please let me know how to modify the below posted code in such way that the setter method is invoked and work appropriately

**code**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  <input v-model="inputFirstName" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
  <input v-model="inputLastName" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
  <span>fullName:{{fullname}}</span>
  <button @click="incrementNum">counter: {{counter}}</button>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>

import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { computed, ref } from 'vue' 

const inputFirstName = ref("")
const inputLastName = ref("")
let counter = ref(0)

const fullname=computed(()=>{
  console.log("fullname computed");
  get() {
    inputFirstName.value + " " + inputLastName.value
  },
  set(value) {
    const splitted = value.split(" ")
    inputFirstName.value = splitted[0] 
    inputLastName.value = splitted[1] 
  }
  
})

const incrementNum=(e)=>{
  counter.value++
  fullname = counter.value.toString() + " " + counter.value.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed) show that there is no arrow function used with getter/setter

```js
const fullname=computed({
  get() {
    return inputFirstName.value + " " + inputLastName.value
  },
  set(value) {
    const splitted = value.split(" ")
    inputFirstName.value = splitted[0] 
    inputLastName.value = splitted[1] 
  }
})
```

Comment: I think you forgot adding "return" in the body of the getter-method of the computed property..would you please add it!